# Labeling faceted plot with ggrepel and jittered dots

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrepel

I am trying to plot three boxplots and label always the 2 highest values.

I tried creating a position element and use this to get same position for points and labels, but somehow this does not work.

```
set.seed(1)
df <- 
  data.frame(a=rep(letters, 3),
             b=LETTERS[1:3],
             int=runif(78, 15, 30))
jitter_pos <- position_jitter(width=.4, seed = 1)
ggplot(df,
       aes(1, int,
           color=b)) +
  geom_point(position=jitter_pos) +
  geom_boxplot(alpha=.3, outlier.shape=NA, fill=NA, color='#993404') +
  facet_wrap(~ b) +
  guides(color=FALSE) +
  geom_label_repel(data=df %>%
                     group_by(b) %>%
                     arrange(desc(int)) %>%
                     slice(1:2),
                   aes(label=a),
                   size=2.5, color='black',
                   fill='#FFFFFF33',
                   box.padding=1,
                   position=jitter_pos)
```

I am pretty sure it is just a little mistake but somehow I can't find my error. The labels do not match the dot positions.

Maybe a better solution would be with `b` on the x axis and using `jitterdodge` somehow, but this didn't worked ether, so I tried to get it running with facets. So nothing works for me yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake is in `position_jitter`'s behavior and the issue is discussed at length in [this github issue](https://github.com/slowkow/ggrepel/issues/123).

The solution suggested by the ggrepel author is to add an explicit `label` column to the dataframe, with empty strings for the rows you want to omit:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)
df <- 
  data.frame(a=rep(letters, 3),
             b=LETTERS[1:3],
             int=runif(78, 15, 30)) %>%
  group_by(b) %>%
  mutate(label = if_else(rank(-int) %in% 1:2, as.character(a), ""))
jitter_pos <- position_jitter(width=.4, height = 0, seed = 1)



ggplot(df,
       aes(1, int,
           color=b)) +
  geom_jitter(position=jitter_pos) +
  geom_boxplot(alpha=.3, outlier.shape=NA, fill=NA, color='#993404') +
  guides(color=FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~ b) +
  geom_label_repel(aes(x=1, y=int, label=label),
                   size=2.5, color='black',
                   fill='#FFFFFF33',
                   box.padding=1,
                   position=jitter_pos)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-09-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I saw this way once in a while but haven't tried it on this dataset and I thought the issue might be somewhere else... Thanks, it works like a charm now.